# How can i animate hamburger drawer icon

Tags: android, animation, navigation-drawer

I have to animate a drawer icon. The red circle needs to pop up in the same way as in the gif below. Any of the animation styles are fine, I only want to know if I can create an animation like these. Any thoughts?

[image]

I have searched the internet, but I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: You can use bounce effect for that with visibility. Currently I am using mobile so I can't give you example but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the scale animation, for example, to get a similar effect of the pop animation in that gif you could do the following:

Create a file `res/anim/bounce.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">

    <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXScale="1.5"
        android:fromYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" />

</set>
```

And then load the animation:

```
Animation bounceAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.bounce);
yourView.startAnimation(bounceAnimation);
```